# How to prevent CreateProcess/ShellExecute from resetting Windows idle timer?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, idle-timer

I need to launch an app from my app. I tried to use `CreateProcess` and `ShellExecute` but they both reset windows idle timer (which is used for monitor and system sleep). Is it possible to prevent this behavior?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would appear implausible that `CreateProcess` were to reset Windows' idle timer. How have you verified this to be the case?

Comment: Transition from active to idle is not as simple as an "idle timer" thing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/transitioning-between-idle-and-active-states#transitioning-from-active-to-idle try the SleepStudy tool first to check what's really going on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby-sleepstudy

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks! You are right, the issue is not related with CreateProcess/ShellExecute. It seems opening any windowed app resets idle timer. For example, if I open notepad.exe in for-loop with 1 min delay, the monitor never turn off.

Comment: @SimonMourier, thanks! But the Sleep Study tool is useful for system power events but I'm more interested in monitor power-off events.

Comment: Read the links "Windows includes a built-in diagnostic tool called SleepStudy to help discover which of these conditions is not being met when the SoC is prevented from entering the idle (DRIPS) state.".

Comment: That, too, sounds implausible. The timeout values correspond to user interaction. Launching a GUI process does not reset the last input timestamp as reported by `GetLastInputInfo`. The conclusion you arrived at is probably inaccurate. Something else seems to be going on.